# What is the reasoning behind sf::Sprites owning their position and rotation? It's muddling up my Component/Entity/System

Tags: c++, sdl, sfml

I am making a basic implementation of Asteroids using SFML in C++, to practice using a component-entity-system framework.

Conceptually, it makes sense for objects like the player ship, floating asteroids etc. to share common 'components', such as a graphics component, a velocity component, and an orientation/positional component. This keeps concerns separate and has a whole range of benefits.

However, in SFML, Sprites are rendered to a fixed position that only they know about! This immediately means that my graphics component and orientation/positional component must be combined or must know about each other, which goes against the whole idea of the component-entity-system approach. In SDL, on the other hand, you can easily render the texture to a separate rectangle constructed from anywhere.

My question is this: There must be some concrete reasoning behind why Sprites in SFML hang onto their own positional information - what is this reasoning? Perhaps if I understood this better, I could form a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sf::Sprite` class is basically meant to be a quick way to draw sprites in an easy to use manner.

They're not necessarily the best for more advanced use cases, mostly because they're rather slow (since they're unbatched).

`sf::Sprite` is primarily geared to someone wanting to get a sprite on screen easily without worrying too much about implementation details (as are other `sf::Drawable` derived classes).

What you should do instead is implementing your own drawable or visual component that stores color, texture, and UV coordinate. Mabye something like this:

```
struct DrawableComponent {
    sf::Color color;
    sf::Texture *texture;
    sf::IntRect uv;
}
```

Of course there could be other approaches with more options or various components (e.g. vector graphics vs. textured quads).

Then, when drawing, iterate over all your entities with the same texture that can be batched and put their vertices into a `std::vector` or `sf::VertexArray` and use those for quick, batched rendering.

Answer (score 2):

SFML follows an object-oriented design. A `sf::Sprite` models a visible thing, which has a texture and a transformation. Thus, as usual in OOD, it holds both of these attributes.

This is directly at odds with ECS design, which strives to turn this inside-out by not having entities hold onto anything. You won't really be able to integrate the `sf::Sprite` class into your design -- it's fundamentally incompatible. The best you can do is create a temporary `sf::Sprite` at display time, when you have gathered all of the data you need.

As for SDL... Well, unlike SFML, it's just a low-ish-level graphics API (among others). It does not try to model anything: take a texture, slap it on the framebuffer, that's it. Two very different tools for very different goals.